# Spring boot scheduled cron jobs run 2 times when deployed more than one instance

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

I have four cron jobs in the application and they work some hours in the day. I deployed them in 6 different instance and I use shedLock to prevent overlapping but it wasn't enough. Because sometimes job delay and lock is removed, then job work 2 times again. How can I configure that if a cron job still working in the one instance, other instances don't start job till this one finish?

Comment: Use something like quartz, which uses a central storage for the job information. Shedlock will not solve that it will only lock for some time, if your job takes longer/shorter and there is a timing difference on the nodes it still will run multiple times.

Comment: You can use jobrunr which supports distributed scheduling of jobs

Answer (score 0):

why not use distribute executor?if you deployed them in multiple instance,you must  manage and schedule the instance's status,for example instance A run  at t1,instance B run at t2,it's very complex.You can deployed them on instance or selected distribute schedule executor,in all distribute system, status manage is very difficulty

Answer (score 0):

Try deploying Spring Boot Scheduled Cron jobs one at a time to prevent them being deployed more than one instance